# Proguard dontwarn command for duplicate zip entry?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

After migration to AndroidX proguard fails with:

```
EXEC : warning : Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [B:\Bamboo-build-dir\PGP-ALLPLATFORMS-JOB1\build\android\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\Google\release\0.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\buildsrv\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\6973853fc6cf653ca71c47008b82982d\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v4/c/c$a.class == classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.class]))
```

How do I disable this warning with `dontwarn` ?

Comment: Try cleaning your project first and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Nicolas it does. Have you ever encountered such issue? Or perhaps, know how to disable the Proguard warning?

Comment: No, I just figured this might be a cache issue and cleaning would help. Does building work when proguard is disabled?